# Final Cut Pro X editing multiple overlayed images

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

This is less a direct problem more a query on the best way to handle things.  I do a lot of videos that end up with a lot of overlayed graphics, the videos are a boardgame and the overlays are the cards held in the players hands.  I cant video the hands so I scan the cards and overlay them afterwards in FCPX and then animate them in and out as required, but this leads me to have loooooads of layers in the end.  Im wondering if there is an easier way at all to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a compound clip for the hand of one player with the cards inside. That would reduce the main timeline from look confusing with too many clips attached.

Comment: Do compound clips add overly to the background rendering?  And when I want to then modify the layout of the cards (for example as they are played etc bringing them to the center of the screen when the player announces they are being played) is there a way to go to that point in the compound clip easily or do I just have to note the time that Im at then go into it and scroll to the right point?

Comment: I am not sure about the background rendering but my guess compound clips have no effect. Normally I have background rendering completely off, as I mainly work with proxies. Just for the export, I change to original media. When place your playhead at the position you want to edit and click 'Open Clip' the playhead is at the corresponding position in the compound clip.